# Extract 'tos' data from NetCDF file when lat and lon are double in R

Tags: r, arrays, matrix, netcdf, temperature

This is my first time on stack overflow, and my coding skills are pretty bad
I am working with a NetCDF file of historical tos.
I would like to extract tos data for specific lat and lon. I have the tos data in an array with three dimensions and the lon and lat are each in a matrix with 2 dimensions.
The problem is that the row-column combination of my selected lon and lat do not correspond with the row-col combination of the tos array.
Here below the code I have so far

```
# Open a NetCDF file
library('ncdf4')
library('raster') 
library('rgdal') 
library('ggplot2')
hist_acc <- "tos_Omon_ACCESS-ESM1-5_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_185001-201412.nc"
hist_acc1 <- nc_open(hist_acc)
# Get Latitude, Longitude and time from the Netcdf File
lon_1 <- ncvar_get(hist_acc1, "longitude")
lat_1 <- ncvar_get(hist_acc1, "latitude")
tt <- ncvar_get(hist_acc1, "time")
#Extract Temperature of the surface data and substitue fillvalue with NA and close the NetCDF file to leave more space
tos_array <- ncvar_get(hist_acc1, "tos")
fillvalue<- ncatt_get(hist_acc1, "tos", "_FillValue")
tos_array[tos_array == fillvalue$value] <- NA
nc_close(hist_acc1)
# Extract row and column numbers with specific longitudes
wnf_lon <- which(lon_1 > 7 & lon_1 < 8, arr.ind=TRUE) 
rows_wnf_lon <- wnf_lon[,1] 
col_wnf_lon <- wnf_lon[, 2] 
#Extract row and column numbers with specific latitudes
wnf_lat <- which(lat_1 > 61 & lat_1 < 62, arr.ind=TRUE)
rows_wnf_lat <- wnf_lat[,1] 
col_wnf_lat <- wnf_lat[,2] 
# Extract 1 matrix from array (e g day 1)
day1 <- tos_array[, ,1]
```

I got stuck here because the row and colums numbers of my lat and lon matrix do not correspond to the row and col number for the tos day1 array.

Let me know if you don t understand my question and I will try to be more specific.
If you have resources for NetCDF file manipulation in R please let me know
Thank you in advance
Riccardo

Answer (score 0):

The easier way to access such data is like this

```
library(terra)
f <- "tos_Omon_ACCESS-ESM1-5_historical_r1i1p1f1_gn_185001-201412.nc"
r <- rast(f)
r
plot(r, 1)
```

And perhaps look [here](https://rspatial.org/terra) if you are not familiar with spatial (raster) data manipulation in R

Comment: Thank you Robert
I tried that, but it seems that the file is not a regular grid so when I convert it to a raster the projection is wrong